# Background-rgba doesn't work on simple snippet?

Tags: html, css, background-color

Have tried this for half an hour now and I still don't get why such a simple snippet won't have background-color:

```css
#section3 {
  z-index: 5;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

h3 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10vh;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<span id="section3">
    <h3>Unser Anspruch</h3>
</span>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qhdaz/2059/)

Comment: Using a `h3` inside a `span` is invalid. A `span` can only contain other `inline` elements, but not `block` one's, as a `h3` is. Change your `span` to e.g. a `section` and it will work: http://jsfiddle.net/Qhdaz/2061/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`span` is an inline-block element, hence it cannot be given height

Inorder to give it height, u will have to convert it into `display:block` or `display:inline block`

But as @LGSon said, `h3` must never be put inside a `span` element

Instead of using `span`, use a `div` as `div` is `display:block`
 by default

```css
#section3 {
    z-index: 5;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: rgba(250,0,0,1);
   }

h3{

    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:10vh;
    font-size: 2em;

}
```

```html
<div id="section3">

            <h3>Unser Anspruch</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: you should change span to div instead of making the span block

Comment: I could have sworn I tried this, since this seems so obvious but apparently I didn't haha :) thanks so much, I of course knew about the differences between div and span as inline and block elements, and that span doesn't have a height only seems logic, but I never actually saw it like this. Thank you for solving my problem and teaching me something new haha :) have a great day